# Multiple iframe videos running one at the time

Tags: javascript, iframe, video

I'm using this video script - http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/ - and I'm having problem when running multiple videos in the same html page, one for each section. They all start at the same time and it's always running the same video from the first link.

```
<section id="section-1">
<div class="header-video">
<img src=""
            class="header-video__media"
            data-video-URL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yNHyTk2jYNA"
            data-teaser="video/teaser-video"
            data-video-width="560"
            data-video-height="315">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yNHyTk2jYNA" class="header-video__play-trigger" id="header-video__play-trigger">View Trailer</a>
            <button type="button" class="header-video__close-trigger" id="header-video__close-trigger">Close</button>
        </div>
</section>

<section id="section-2">
<div class="header-video">
<img src=""
            class="header-video__media"
            data-video-URL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NX7QNWEGcNI"
            data-teaser="video/teaser-video"
            data-video-width="560"
            data-video-height="315">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NX7QNWEGcNI" class="header-video__play-trigger" id="header-video__play-trigger">View Trailer</a>
            <button type="button" class="header-video__close-trigger" id="header-video__close-trigger">Close</button>
        </div>
</section>

<script>
$('.header-video').each(function(i, elem) {
    headerVideo = new HeaderVideo({
    element: elem,
    media: '.header-video__media',
    playTrigger: '.header-video__play-trigger',
    closeTrigger: '.header-video__close-trigger'
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like to play one at the time with the correct youtube link for each.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are looping through your `.header-video` elements and passing the right `elem`, you are not saying which `.header-video_media` to use, try:

```
$('.header-video').each(function(i, elem) {
    headerVideo = new HeaderVideo({
        element: elem,
        media: $(elem).find('.header-video__media'),
        playTrigger: $(elem).find('.header-video__play-trigger'),
        closeTrigger: $(elem).find('.header-video__close-trigger')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I really appreciate your help.  Its working smooth now.

Comment: No problem, it;s an easy mistake to make, glad I could help